# Sed replace regular expression by capture group match

Tags: regex, sed

I am attempting to use `sed` to replace a regular expression capture group. I've read that this requires enabling extended regular expressions with the `-E` flag. However, the following command is still not updating the text as expected.

```sh
echo "master-abcdef" | sed -i '' -E "s/IMAGE_TAG:\s*(\S+)$/\1/g" values.yaml
```

Where `values.yaml` has contents of:

```
global:
  env: default

default:
  IMAGE_TAG: dev-0be3323.zgm9a
  ... (more text below)
```

I am expecting `values.yaml` to be replaced to:

```
global:
  env: default

default:
  IMAGE_TAG: master-abcdef
  ... (more text below)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```sh
repl="master-abcdef"
sed -i '' -E "s/(IMAGE_TAG:[[:space:]]*).*/\\1$repl/" values.yaml
```

Here,

- `(IMAGE_TAG:[[:space:]]*)` - captures into `\1` an `IMAGE_TAG:` string and then any zero or more whitespaces
- `.*` - matches the rest of the string (here, line).

The `\1$repl` replacement puts the captured value + the `repl` value in place of the matched text.

Answer (score 3):

You may use this in any version `sed`:

```sh
sed -i.bak -E 's/(IMAGE_TAG:[[:blank:]]+)[^[:blank:]]+/\1master-abcdef/' file.yml

cat file.yml

global:
  env: default

default:
  IMAGE_TAG: master-abcdef
  ... (more text below)
```

Here `[[:blank:]]` matches a space or tab.

If you are using `gnu-sed` then use:

```
sed -i -E 's/(IMAGE_TAG:\s+)\S+/\1master-abcdef/' file.yml
```

Answer (score 3):

With [yq](/questions/tagged/yq), you can write

```sh
yq eval '.default.IMAGE_TAG = "master-abcdef"' values.yaml
```